# React Native Animation on Image List to Create Infinite Loop on Scroll

Tags: react-native, animation

I'd like to have an image list that goes from bottom to up (half of the page) with an infinite loop and continues without any stop but the Animation stops and the images goes back as they're placed at first.

What I mean is I have 5 images and I show only 2 of them on the screen and I'd like to make an auto scroll animation that shows the images and goes up, when the images finishes it should continue the images left and sequence the same images as queue.

The order should be like:

- Img1
- Img2
- Img3
- Img1
- Img2
- Img3

[image: The infinite loop on going up]

```js
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Image, Animated, StyleSheet, Easing } from 'react-native';

import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';
import classNames from 'classnames';

import { COLORS } from '@app/constants';

type VerticalSliderPropTypes = {
  direction?: 'bottom' | 'top';
  slideContainerClassName?: string;
  imageList: HTMLImageElement[];
};

const MARGIN_TOP_HEIGHT = 10;
const IMAGE_HEIGHT = 134;
const SCROLL_HEIGHT = IMAGE_HEIGHT + MARGIN_TOP_HEIGHT;

const VerticalSlider: React.FC<VerticalSliderPropTypes> = ({ direction = 'top', imageList, slideContainerClassName }) => {
  const newImageList = [...imageList, ...imageList];

  const scrollY = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  useEffect(() => {
    const scroll = Animated.timing(scrollY, {
      toValue: -SCROLL_HEIGHT,
      duration: 7000,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    });

    const loop = Animated.loop(scroll);
    loop.start();

    return () => {
      loop.stop();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <View className="h-200 w-102 bg-background">
      <LinearGradient colors={[COLORS.BACKGROUND, COLORS.LIGHT_2]} style={styles.gradient} />
      <View>
        <View className={classNames('-z-z', slideContainerClassName)}>
          <Animated.View
            style={[
              styles.imageContainer,
              {
                transform: [
                  {
                    translateY: scrollY,
                  },
                ],
              },
            ]}
          >
            {newImageList.map((image, index) => (
              <Image resizeMode="cover" className="w-102 h-134 rounded-20 mt-10 " key={index} source={image} />
            ))}
          </Animated.View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  gradient: {
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 1,
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
  },
  imageContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
});

export default VerticalSlider;
```